# Restriction of a quadratic form with signature $(1, n-1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I want to prove the following fact. Let $f$ be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear function on a vector space $V$ with positive index of inertia equal to 1. And let $f(x,x) > 0$ for some vector $x \in V$. Then restriction of $f$ to any subspace $W$ that contains $v$ is nondegenerate.

I know that if $f|_U$ is nondegenerate then $V = U \oplus U^\perp$ (with respect to $f$). So $W = \langle x \rangle \oplus W'$, where $W'$ is the orthogonal complement of $\langle x \rangle$ in $W$ with respect to $W$. Maybe it's possible to show that $f|_{W'}$ is positive definite, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Take $f(v,v)=-v_1^2-v_2^2+v_3^2$ for $v\in V=\mathbb R^3$. Let $x=(1,0,0)$ and $y=(0,1,1)$, so $f(x,x)<0$; but the subspace spanned by $x$ and $y$ is degenerate.

Comment: @mr_e_man, you are right. But there was a critical typo in the question. It should be $f(x,x) > 0$, not $f(x,x) < 0$.

Comment: That has no influence, just replace $f$ by $-f$.

Comment: someone just asked a duplicate of this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445844/a-non-degenerate-subspace-of-minkowski-space/

Comment: @CaptainLama - But $-f$ has positive index of inertia equal to $2$, not $1$.